# When $cov(Z_s,Z_u)=\sigma^2_{\max(s,u)}$ for normal random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, covariance

Let $Z_1, Z_2, \dots, Z_n$ be normal random variables with mean zero and $Var(Z_i)=\sigma_i^2$.
Under what condition $cov(Z_s,Z_u)=\sigma^2_{\max(s,u)}$?

Comment: What attempt have you made to solve this question? What is meant by *under what condition*? The covariance matrix is quite simple to determine, what else could be required?

Comment: @Jack Neubecker : there are no conditions other than the ones mentioned. We are not looking for the covariance matrix, we want to see how each covariance can have the above value.

Answer (score -1):

I will only consider the $n=2$ case for a counter-example, as my linear algebra is not strong. But a covariance matrix M must be positive semi-definite, i.e. $z^T M z \geq 0$ for all column vectors $z$ of length $n$. As you have defined it, the covariance matrix would be of the form $M = (a,b;b,b)$, for some $a,b > 0$. Let $z = (x;y)$. Then to be positive semi-definite, $ax^2 + 2bxy + by^2 = ax^2 + b(2xy + y^2)\geq 0$ for all $x,y$ (this expression can be obtained by standard matrix operations). Only $b(2xy + y^2)$ can be negative, so we need $ax^2 \geq -b(2xy + y^2)$. For any $y, a, b$ there should be a suitable $x$ which breaks this inequality, so we have shown that this matrix cannot be a covariance matrix.